# Mark row before count starts again

Tags: r, dplyr

```
shift = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
count =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
test <- cbind(shift,count)
```

So I am trying to mark every last row for every shift (so rows with `count = c(8,10,7)`with a binary 1 and every other row with 0. Right now I am thinking maybe that is possible with a left join but I am not quite sure. I would prefer not working with loops but rather use some techniques from dplyr. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to add a new 0/1 column `last` that contains a 1 in the last row of each shift and that the shifts are contiguous, here are two base R approaches:

```
transform(test, last = ave(count, shift, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))

transform(test, last = +!duplicated(shift, fromLast = TRUE))
```

or with dplyr use `mutate`:

```
test %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(shift) %>%
  mutate(last = +(1:n() == n())) %>%
  ungroup

test %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(last = +!duplicated(shift, fromLast = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, G. Grothendieck. The first one seems to work nicely with the test data however, I do not really work with my actual data. Can I ask why you use the `ave()` command in the first solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   group_by(shift) %>% 
   mutate(is_last = ifelse( row_number() == max(row_number()), 1, 0)) %>% 
   ungroup()
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   shift count is_last
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1     1       0
 2     1     2       0
 3     1     3       0
 4     1     4       0
 5     1     5       0
 6     1     6       0
 7     1     7       0
 8     1     8       1
 9     2     1       0
10     2     2       0
# … with 15 more rows
```